# How do i modify my code below using Caesar Cipher - JAVA

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, shift, caesar-cipher

I want to implement a Caesar Cipher shift to shift each letter to the left in a string by 2 .The code above shift the words right by 2 using Caeser Cipher,How do I modify my code it to make it shift left by 2. For example, “Jgnnq vjgtg!” with a shift of 2 will become “Hello there!"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(caesarEncrypt("Hello there!", 2)); 
    }

    public static String caesarEncrypt(String ss, int shift){
        String s = "";
        int len = ss.length();
        for(int x = 0; x < len; x++){
            char c = (char)(ss.charAt(x) + shift);
            if (c > 'z') {
                s += (char)(ss.charAt(x) - (26-shift));
            }
            else {
                s += (char)(ss.charAt(x) + shift);
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// import required classes and package, if any    
import java.util.Scanner;   
   
// create class CaesarCipherExample for encryption and decryption    
public class CaesarCipherExample   
{   
    // ALPHABET string denotes alphabet from a-z   
    public static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";   
      
    // create encryptData() method for encrypting user input string with given shift key   
    public static String encryptData(String inputStr, int shiftKey)   
    {   
        // convert inputStr into lower case   
        inputStr = inputStr.toLowerCase();   
          
        // encryptStr to store encrypted data   
        String encryptStr = "";   
          
        // use for loop for traversing each character of the input string   
        for (int i = 0; i < inputStr.length(); i++)   
        {   
            // get position of each character of inputStr in ALPHABET   
            int pos = ALPHABET.indexOf(inputStr.charAt(i));   
              
            // get encrypted char for each char of inputStr   
            int encryptPos = (shiftKey + pos) % 26;   
            char encryptChar = ALPHABET.charAt(encryptPos);   
              
            // add encrypted char to encrypted string   
            encryptStr += encryptChar;   
        }   
          
        // return encrypted string   
        return encryptStr;   
    }   
      
    // create decryptData() method for decrypting user input string with given shift key   
    public static String decryptData(String inputStr, int shiftKey)   
    {   
        // convert inputStr into lower case   
        inputStr = inputStr.toLowerCase();   
          
        // decryptStr to store decrypted data   
        String decryptStr = "";   
          
        // use for loop for traversing each character of the input string   
        for (int i = 0; i < inputStr.length(); i++)   
        {   
              
            // get position of each character of inputStr in ALPHABET   
            int pos = ALPHABET.indexOf(inputStr.charAt(i));   
              
            // get decrypted char for each char of inputStr   
            int decryptPos = (pos - shiftKey) % 26;   
              
            // if decryptPos is negative   
            if (decryptPos < 0){   
                decryptPos = ALPHABET.length() + decryptPos;   
            }   
            char decryptChar = ALPHABET.charAt(decryptPos);   
              
            // add decrypted char to decrypted string   
            decryptStr += decryptChar;   
        }   
        // return decrypted string   
        return decryptStr;   
    }   
      
    // main() method start   
    public static void main(String[] args)   
    {   
        // create an instance of Scanner class   
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);   
          
        // take input from the user   
        System.out.println("Enter a string for encryption using Caesar Cipher: ");   
        String inputStr = sc.nextLine();   
          
        System.out.println("Enter the value by which each character in the plaintext message gets shifted: ");   
        int shiftKey = Integer.valueOf(sc.nextLine());   
          
        System.out.println("Encrypted Data ===> "+encryptData(inputStr, shiftKey));   
        System.out.println("Decrypted Data ===> "+decryptData(encryptData(inputStr, shiftKey), shiftKey));   
          
        // close Scanner class object   
        sc.close();   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but can you just modify my code above because i know im almost there. Thank you